# By transforming to polar co-ordinates, evaluate the following integral.

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

By transforming to polar co-ordinates, evaluate the following integral:

[image: Question]

Converting the Integrand is simple for me, but I am confused on how I can convert the limits - how can I visual this region?

Comment: That's the graph of a hyperbola

Comment: Well, you can't convert the limit-boundary $y=x$ because you end up with $r={0\over\sin\theta-\cos\theta}$.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley, do you think there is something wrong with the question?

Comment: @Mathematica No actually, I was fooled! https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kywphz3yj9 <-- will show you the region. It's bounded by r=0 and r=a from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kywphz3yj9

After analyzing the bounds, we can see that this is a section of a circle, bounded by $y=x$, $y=$ [circle of radius $a$], $x=0$, and $x=a/\sqrt2$. This transforms into $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$ from $x=0\ \&\ y=x$ stopped at $x=a/\sqrt2$. And then $r$ is easy because it's the region inside a circle of radius $a$: $0\le r\le a$. $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}d\theta \cdot \int_{0}^{a} r^2\,dr$$

Comment: To clarify, it's always $\int r\cdot dA$, and $dA$ in this case is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. If we use $r^2=x^2+y^2$, then we get $\int r \cdot r$ = $\int r^2 dr$. Cheers!